# What observations will Cassini take during its "Grand Finale"?

Tags: saturn, cassini

Cassini's [Grand Finale](https://saturn.jpl.nasa.gov/mission/grand-finale/overview/) is underway. What special observations will be taken during this time that were not possible before the Grand Finale?

Comment: What about special observations do you miss in the linked page about Grand Finale? The information is there.